# Conditional CHECK constraint

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, check-constraints

In Postgresql 11.5 I want to have a table store file hashes and their respective filenames, as well as a date as to when this information was processed. Instead of having an `available` BOOLEAN column I would rather put `DELETED!` into the `crc32` column.

Like this table:

```
 filename |  crc32   |   date
----------+----------+------------
 FOO.doc  | 005929FA | 2015-03-14
 bar.txt  | C5907C6A | 2015-03-14
 FOO.doc  | 2AF317BB | 2016-08-22
 bar.txt  | DELETED! | 2018-11-30
 bar.txt  | AC0132D9 | 2019-09-10
```

This table shows the file history from a directory.

- 1st run:  `FOO.doc` was checked first and its hash (at the time) was added. Same deal with `bar.txt`.
- 2nd run:  `FOO.doc`'s hash changed so a second entry was added. `bar.txt`'s entry was left alone since its hash remained the same.
- 3rd run:  `bar.txt` was deleted, `FOO.doc` remained untouched since last time.
- 4th run:  `bar.txt` was added again and `FOO.doc` remained untouched again.

The thing about this table is, I have a CHECK constraint that allows only this regex to be entered into the crc32 column: `^[0-9A-F]{8}$|^DELETED\!$`

I want to make this a bit stricter. I want Postgresql to error out when I try to use `DELETED!` if the file was never in the table before. So if I try adding an entry like: `INSERT INTO hist VALUES ('egg.txt', 'DELETED!', '2019-09-23');` it will error out. If I try `INSERT INTO hist VALUES ('FOO.doc', 'DELETED!', '2019-09-23');` it will work since `FOO.doc` was there already.

So basically `DELETED!` can only be used when the file in question already has an entry in the table.

Is this possible? I hope this makes sense. If I didn't explain this enough let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Combining two different types of information in a single column is usually not a really good idea. I would go for a boolean column `is_deleted` (or something similar). Alternatively I would set the value of `crc32` to `null` to indicate that the file has been deleted

Comment: to add to @a_horse_with_no_name . . .  i would not use crc32 especially not when you use that hash to see if  content changed... As crc32 has collision probabilities much higher then sha(256/512) that is then two totally different messages ends into having same hash

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Good idea. Now if I were to add such a column, what constraint would I need to basically say "if `crc32` is null, `is_deleted` MUST be true." I'd like to implement both so if a user sees a null value it's available status is a bit clearer

Comment: @RaymondNijland Oh I know, in reality I will be using SHA256 but in my example I wanted things to be short and clean-looking. But thanks regardless for the input

Comment: @leetbacoon: why don't you create a view that simply returns `crc32 is null as is_deleted`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this CHECK constraint and it appears to work.

```
CHECK (crc32 IS NULL AND is_deleted = 't' OR crc32 IS NOT NULL AND is_deleted = 'f')
```

Answer (score 1):

That additional requirement would best be met with a `BEFORE` trigger:

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_upd() RETURNS trigger
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$$BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM my_table
                  WHERE filename = NEW.filename)
   THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'cannot delete a non-existing row';
   END IF;

   RETURN NEW;
END;$$;

CREATE TRIGGER check_upd BEFORE INSERT ON my_table
   FOR EACH ROW WHEN (NEW.crc32 = 'DELETED!')
EXECUTE PROCEDURE check_upd();
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a small mistake: it should be `BEFORE INSERT`, nit `BEFORE UPDATE`.

Comment: Works perfect, thank you! I found that a mixture of both answers seems to be the most integral. (of course, changing `(NEW.crc32 = 'DELETED!')` to `(NEW.is_deleted = 't')`)